# Should I embed or extend python to create high quality, high speed GUI programs?

Tags: python, c, user-interface, cross-platform

I'm trying to find a way to rapidly develop (or rather eventually reach a point where I can rapidly develop) very nice looking cross platform GUI desktop apps that have a very small footprint on disk and in memory, launch very fast (much faster, for example, than even a bare bones wxPython window) (for a good example, look at how fast TextEdit launches under OSX.  That's the kind of launch speed I want for my GUI apps), deploy easily, and interact very well with the operating system (Gimp and Gedit and various other open source, cross platform apps exhibit various behaviors that I really hate, depending on the platform, but especially on OSX) without spending any money.  (Hey, stop laughing! =P)

I'm dissatisfied with wxWidgets, Qt, SDL, and everything else I've tried so far, so I'm down to writing native GUI code (especially the part that interacts with the OS's windowing system) on each platform, using native tools (XCode/ObjC/Cocoa/OpenGL, MSVC/Win32/DirectX, gcc/GTK/OpenGL), and then trying to come up with some way of writing as much as possible of the rest of the program in Python.

I've thought about maybe writing a set of shared libraries / dll's to deal with matters GUI, and then wrapping them with a set of Python C extensions, but there are some technical challenges involved in doing that when it comes to packaging (menus, the app icon, certain OS-specific application manifests, etc), and I'm not sure that launch speed and performance in general will be acceptable, depending on the particular program I'm writing.

So I've thought about maybe creating a sort of a "shell" program on each platform, and embedding python, kind of in a similar way to the way Sublime Text 2 does.

I don't like the startup slowness that occurs when launching any python program for the first time.  I was hoping this was a result of compiling to byte code, and that I could just include precompiled versions of python modules with my apps, but from experimenting, it seems this is not the case.. it seems that the first time anything python runs (since the last system reboot), a shared library / dll is loaded or something.  So that's one reason I think of maybe embedding Python - I wonder if there are some options available when imbedding/calling python that could help reduce that launch delay.  Or if worst comes to worst, in the imbedded case I can launch without Python, then launch Python if/when I need to, asynchronously (not in the main thread), after the app has already launched.

Is there a way to reduce the first-time launch delay for deployed python programs (ie., programs who's packages include a version of the intepreter.. maybe the interpreter can be compiled with switches I haven't tried)?

Is there any way to reduce the interpreter load/initialize delay when embedding python?

Is it completely unrealistic to expect any python gui program to launch as fast or have as small a footprint as TextEdit?

Answer (score 2):

[Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/download.html)

It doesn't get any better, you'll get full support for all Python releases,
you're in charge of your GUI code and the speed of the thing is phenomenal.
You can render chunks of data without noticeable lag!

Running on a **333Mhz** CPU with less then **128MB** and some random **PCI graphics card** i've managed to pull this out of a hat:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7zFLQZxzcY
(Roughly a few hunder thousand stars, scale:able, a few hundred planets also in scale witha a ship that can be navigated in space.. this was a early development video for something i didn't have time to finish)

AFter the first run (or if you compile your .py into .pyc) you'll get a great speed out of your GUI using pyglet, but you'll have to create all your input and buttons your self since you're writing graphical data and not interface code.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised I haven't come across this before, thanks for pointing it out.  

Questions:

-Run speed looks good, but how fast is the launch speed?  
-How do you set the packaged application icon?
-How do you set the packaged initial app menu under OSX?  
-Is it slow and laggy under OSX?

Setting the app icon at runtime doesn't produce an icon for desktop links, and using a blank initial menu has created behavior issues for me before.  One list poster says it's slow and laggy under OSX, and that's been my experience with SDL, too.  Maybe Pyglet and SDL use the same interfaces..

Comment: Launch speed (when running from .pyc) is also great, at least that is my experience dealing with it.
Assuming you know the main traps with the Python language itself you can get away with instant upstarts without a problem.
Using UPX, to quote pyinstaller - "On both Windows and Linux, UPX can give truly startling compression - the days of fitting something useful on a diskette are not gone forever!" :)
The'res tons of information on how to setup icons in the GUI itself, otherwise just use your packaging applications choice of icon (i use pywininstaller or py2exe/py2app). Pyglet Cocoa in OSX

Comment: So speed shouldn't be an issue in OSX since it uses the native rendering alternative for OSX. Besides that Pyglet uses OpenGL C/C++ libraries to get the best result in speed and rendering.
Pyglet also supports multiple monitors which many frameworks forget to include (draging a 3D rendered window in Windows can be a dreadful task across multiple monitors because Python (wxPython for instance) usually starts up the rendered on the screen it's launched from, and doesn't bother to render the application on other monitors). There's a jungle of benefits from Pyglet, i'd say give it a try and see :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the openoffice way on windows platform and write a launcher that simply tries to access the file needed by your software, so that they will end up in the memory cache, speeding up the startup time (but creating useless things in the cache, in case the user doesn't want to open your program).